# How to Reject User Input with Loop if it has Special Characters in Python

Tags: python, while-loop, user-input, special-characters

I'm trying to write a program in Python where the user enters an answer and if it's less than 5 characters or has a special character like !, @, #, $, it's supposed to get kicked and the user tries again.

It's okay if something like ),(,*,&,^ gets entered, I just can't have !,@,#,$.

I was wondering if someone could explain it for me better than what my poor Googling found.

Thanks

Here's my code:

```
while True:
    print("Without entering any special characters !, @, #, $")
    answer = input("Please enter an answer >= 5 characters: ")
    if len(answer) >= 5:
        print("Your answer was greater than or equal to 5 characters!")
        print("Success!")
        break
    else:
        print("Please read directions and try again.")
```

Comment: pretty sure theres an "intersection" function or something you can do with lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any to figure out if any character in your `answer` is in `['!','@','#','$']`.

```
if len(answer) >= 5 and not any(i in ['!','@','#','$'] for i in answer):
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
word='yaywords@'
badchars='!@#$'

if len(list(set(list(badchars)) & set(list(word)))) == 0:
    'yay it worked'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take the intersection of the set of characters in the answer with the set bad characters to see if any bad characters are in the answer:

```
if len(answer) >= 5 and not set(answer) & set('!@#$'):
```